# Multiplying subarrays of tensor

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, math, probability

I am trying to implement a multivariate Gaussian Mixture Model and am trying to calculate the probability distribution function using tensors. There are n data points, k clusters, and d dimensions. So far, I have two tensors. One is a `(n,k,d)` tensor of centered data points and the other is a `kxdxd` tensor of covariance matricies. I can compute an `nxk` matrix of probabilities by doing

```
centered = np.repeat(points[:,np.newaxis,:],K,axis=1) - mu[np.newaxis,:] # KxNxD
prob = np.zeros(n,k)
constant = 1/2/np.pow(np.pi, d/2)
for n in range(centered.shape[1]):
    for k in range(centered.shape[0]):
        p = centered[n,k,:][np.newaxis] # 1xN
        power = -1/2*(p @ np.linalg.inv(sigma[k,:,:]) @ p.T)
        prob[n,k] = constant * np.linalg.det(sigma[k,:,:]) * np.exp(power)
```

where `sigma` is the triangularized `kxdxd` matrix of covariances and `centered` are mypoints. What is a more pythonic way of doing this using numpy's tensor capabilites?

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of quick observations:

- I don't see you using `p` in the loop; is this a mistake?  Using `n` instead?
- The `T` in `centered[n,k,:].T` does nothing; with that index the array is 1d
- I'm not sure if `np.linal.inv` can handle batches of arrays, allowing `np.linalg.inv(sigma)`.
- `@` allows batches, just so long as the last 2 dim are the ones entering into the `dot` (with the usual `last of A, 2nd to the last of B` rule; `einsum` can also be used.
- again does `np.linalg.det` handle batches?

Comment: Very sorry about that, I intended the code to be more like pseudocode than something that'd actually run. I've fixed it to make more sense.

Yes, `np.linalg.det` and `np.linalg.inv` handles batches and I get the desired values for each. For `cov_inv` is `kxdxd` matrix where the `dxd` sub matricies of inverses and `cov_det` is a vector of length `k` where each values corresponds to the determinant of the `dxd` matrix in `sigma`